# Google Cloud Security Scanner: Google account authentication error

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I would like to run GCSS against GCE app which is accessible only with Google user/OAuth. But even after trying every possible option for Google account authentication type in Scan configuration I cannot pass config form validation because of "**FAILED_TO_AUTHENTICATE_TO_TARGET**" error. I've tried existing and new user in same domain as the tested app is running in, in other domain, cloud identity, no 2FA, everything... but no success. User+password is correct even after inspecting network request while Scan form is submitting.

Do I have to turn on something else before?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/security-scanner/docs/scanning#create-scan):

> Google enforces a real name policy on Google accounts. If the name on
>   your test account doesn't look real, the account might be blocked.

and

> Two factor authentication is not supported.

In addition check [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/security-scanner/docs/errors):

> start a Chrome incognito session and try to log in with the test
>   credentials on your application.

and try to use Non-Google account for authentication.

**EDIT** I found an issue that looks very familiar to yours at [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135046079). Check it and join this ticket if nothing helped.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for quick hints. I found that google issue after posting this SO question and indeed, it is same problem as mine.